# Loading image from the web at runtime in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to load an image from an url in WPF in a very simple way, but it's not working. Any help ? The code is below :

**Main XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="279*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="41*">                
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="image1" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,10,0"></TextBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            var bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = new Uri("http://www.clipartkid.com/images/817/pic-of-german-flag-clipart-best-VkuN37-clipart.jpeg");
            bi.EndInit();

            //var img = new Image();
            image1.Source = bi;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is ok, and works for me. You may perhaps check your firewall settings. As a note, you don't need to call BeginInit and EndInit. `image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...))` works as well.

Comment: Agree it works for me as well :)

Comment: Just a heads up. Not a good idea. What is the person isn't online or has a slow connection? Why add the latency to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny indeed! Works alright at my other laptop now. Must be something with the firewall settings. And yeps, I've made things even simpler now. Binding the source of the image in XAML to just a string property I've set in a ViewModel class.

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source ="{Binding MyPic}" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
```

---

```
class MyViewModel
    {
        public string MyPic {
            get { return @"http://www.clipartkid.com/images/817/pic-of-german-flag-clipart-best-VkuN37-clipart.jpeg"; }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the responses, and sorry for the confusion.

-Ron